# Rust cargo dylib clarification

Tags: macos, rust, embed, dylib, rust-cargo

I have a Rust project that I want to embed in another application as a dylib. I have `crate_type = ["dylib"]` set in my `Cargo.toml`, but I'm not sure if this should be `cdylib` instead.

When I build the project, it produces a `libfoo.dylib` in `target/debug` as expected, but looking at `otool -L` it also links against a `libfoo.dylib` in `target/debug/deps/`. If I'm going to be using this in another application, will I have to provide both dylibs?

Also, when the crate type is `cdylib`, it'll produce two dylibs as well but the one in deps will have a hash tacked onto the end of the filename. I'm not sure what the difference between these two crate types are.

I can avoid getting two dylibs by using just rustc, however I'd like to use cargo. What is the recommended way of going about embedding Rust as a dylib in other applications?

I'm using Rust on macOS 10.12 if that's significant

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After a bit more research, it turns out `cdylib` statically links the Rust dependencies, and `dylib` is for dynamic linking with other Rust projects.

As for embedding, everything I found suggests that statically linking the Rust library is the recommended way. For using the Rust library dynamically, setting `rpath = true` in my `[profile]` section solved the issues with redundant dylibs.

Comment: What source did you use to discover this in your research?

Comment: @jv-dev It's been a while, so I think the *exact* documentation has changed, but here are two different links talking about linkage in Rust:

https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/command-line-arguments.html?highlight=dylib#--crate-type-a-list-of-types-of-crates-for-the-compiler-to-emit

https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/linkage.html